# Pass GraphUser object from Fragment to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments, facebook-sdk-3.14.x

I'm a new android developer using facebook sdk to login in a Fragment. I want to pass the Graphuser object to another activity which user can edit information and sign up to my app.
this is my request method:

```
private void makeMeRequest(final Session session) {
    // Make an API call to get user data and define a
    // new callback to handle the response.
    final Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session,
            new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    // If the response is successful
                    if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            Intent facebookUserIntent = new Intent(
                                    getActivity().getBaseContext(), Registration.class);
                        }
                    }
                    if (response.getError() != null) {
                        // Handle errors, will do so later.
                    }
                }
            });
    request.executeAsync();
}
```

I want to start the other activity and pass the object and get it on the other one after intent instantiate.
Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

put you graphUser in Shared Preference or make a model extend GraphUser and impliment Serializable.
Pass object of that Model